# Ubuntu 14.04 Direct Rendering Not Working With Nvidia

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

All, I have the xorg-edgers ppa nvidia drivers version 340.

Typing glxinfo shows

```
 name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
```

I tried

```
export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose
glxinfo
```

but that revealed nothing new.

I checked `libGL.so` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and it was pointing to the mesa `libGL.so` I adjusted the soft link to point to the nvidia driver, but it's still not working.

I ran an `ldconfig` nothing.

`ldd /usr/lib/glxinfo` shows it linking to the correct nvidia `libGL.so`

`glxgears` is running very slow

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting my computer, everything was back to normal.

If anyone experiences this, the most probable cause is the `libGL.so` being relinked to mesa. I'm guessing that XServer may have to be restarted after you relink the `libGL.so`

As always, AskUbuntu is devoid of technical support, so much of this is conjecture. Apologies.